# In BigQuery, I want the same result as listagg function in pl/sql. How Can I do it.

Tags: google-bigquery

e.g I have a table with following data

col1    col2
a   Red
a   green
b   blue
b   white
b   yellow
c   orange
c   black

I want the result as 
col1    concatenated_col2
a   red,green
b   blue,white,yellow
c   orange,black
How can I get this in Bigquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT col1, GROUP_CONCAT(col2) AS concatenated_col2
FROM [project:dataset.table]
GROUP BY col1
```